# Circular Imports in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python) have led me to believe that circular imports of modules should work, but I am running into trouble with the following package:

File structure:

```
my_package
--| my_package
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- mod1.py
    |-- mod2.py
--| setup.py
```

`__init__.py`:

```
from . import mod1, mod2
```

`mod1.py`:

```
from . import mod2
```

`mod2.py`:

```
from . import mod1
```

Trying to import the package gives the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'mod1'

What can I do to make these imports work?

Comment: Did you check the second answer? (I strongly recommend restructuring your program to avoid circular imports, though.)

Comment: Python usually will not allow circular references as it will prevent certain garbage collectors from firing and create memory leaks. A good break down of why http://engineering.hearsaysocial.com/2013/06/16/circular-references-in-python/

Comment: I find that usually if you design your structure well, you never need circular dependencies. If mod1 needs stuff from mod2 and vice versa, put the common stuff in a third module, or join the modules.

Comment: @EricThomas: No, circular references are completely permitted. They even changed the `__del__` semantics in recent versions to prevent the memory leak case.